# IntFunction<String> and Function<Integer, String>

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I have following two simple code:

```
IntFunction<String> f1 = Integer::toString;
Function<Integer, String> f2 = Integer::toString;
```

I thought that both definitions are correct and equivalently the same thing, but the second one has compiling errors, complaining that `Required Function<Integer, String>,but Method Reference is found.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second method reference is ambiguous:

both the `static` method

```
public static String toString(int i)
```

and the instance method

```
public String toString()
```

are applicable.

If you write the second assignment using lambda expressions, you can see there are two methods you can use:

```
Function<Integer, String> f2 = i -> Integer.toString (i);
```

or

```
Function<Integer, String> f2 = i -> i.toString ();
```

when you assign `Integer::toString`, the compiler can't decide which method you are referring to.

On the other hand, in the case of `IntFunction<String>`, only `public static String toString(int i)` is applicable.

Comment: Or `Function<Integer, String> f2 = String::valueOf;` to invoke an equivalent `static` method or `Function<Integer, String> f2 = Object::toString;` to get the equivalent to `i -> i.toString()`…